# how to sum with an interval

Tags: excel, intervals

I am looking for a formula or macro which can employ the following: I need to sum-square the amount per week. This should be done from the beginning on. My data structure is as follow:

```
Col A   Col B   Column C
Year    Week    Amount
2000    1       368
2000    2       8646
 …      …       …
2000    52      46846
2001    1       656
2001    2       846
 …      …       …
2001    52      4651
2002    1       489
 …      …       …
2014    52      46546
```

I would have a column D in which I have the sum-squared of the amount per week. So Cell(Column "D", "week 2000w1") should be,

```
=SUMSQ(Amount 2000w1)
```

For the first year, this is easy. The problem occurs in the next year. In Cell (Column "D", week "2001w1") the formula should be,

```
=SUMSQ(Amount 2000w1;Amount 2001w1)
```

For the last year, cell (Column "D", week "2014w1") should be the formula,

```
=SUMSQ(Amount 2000w1;Amount 2001w1; Amount 2002w1;Amount 2003w1;Amount 2004w1; Amount 2005w1;Amount 2006w1;Amount 2007w1; Amount 2008w1;Amount 2009w1;Amount 2010w1; Amount 2011w1;Amount 2012w1;Amount 2013w1)
```

This should be done for the weeks 1 till 52 for all the years. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Is `SUMQ` a custom function or is it a typo in `SUMSQ`? Are you interested in VBA solutions? Judging by your nick, you are...

Comment: Hi, indeed I made a typo. It should be SUMSQ. As I am working with excel I am always interested to gain time by develop a macro. But as I am a novice, I do not understand every VBA solution, while I should be able to understand any function. So both solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution with worksheetfunction, you can develop similar with a macro too, but I think now it's easier without it:

`=SUMSQ(INDEX([Amount]*([Week]=[@Week])*([Year]<=[@Year]),0))`

[image]

Comment: And how can you limit the function for the data from 2005 and on?

Comment: `*[Year]>=2005` each new boolean statement will need to be `TRUE` (unless added). For eaxample if you are looking for weeks 27 and higher in years higher than 2005 or lower than 2001 then `=SUMSQ(INDEX([Amount]*([Week]>=27)*(([Year]<2001)+([Year]>2005)),0))` will be the formula for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Juhász Máté for stealing my jerb. Now I feel dumb for having this developed.
Anyways, here's a VBA solution.
For your sample dataset `=SUMQ($C:$C, $B:$B, $B2)` would give `804,881` i.e. the sum of *week1*s squares.
The advanced use as `=SUMQ($C:$C, $B:$B, $B2, $A:$A, "<=", $A2)` will give `135,424` that is sum of *week1*s for years lower than or equal `2000`.

```
Public Function SUMQ(NumsToSquare As Range, Filter1 As Range, FilterCriterion As Variant, _
                     Optional Filter2 As Range, Optional FilterRelation As String, Optional FilterCriterion2 As Variant) As Long

Set NumsToSquare = Intersect(NumsToSquare, NumsToSquare.Worksheet.UsedRange)
Set Filter1 = Intersect(Filter1, Filter1.Worksheet.UsedRange)
RowsCount = Filter1.Rows.Count
ColumnsCount = Filter1.Columns.Count

If Not Filter2 Is Nothing Then Advanced = True
If Advanced Then Set Filter2 = Intersect(Filter2, Filter2.Worksheet.UsedRange)

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To RowsCount
    For j = 1 To ColumnsCount
        If Not Advanced Then
            If Filter1(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion Then SUMQ = SUMQ + NumsToSquare(i, j).Value2 ^ 2
        Else
            If Filter1(i, j).Value2 = FilterCriterion And Judge(Filter2(i, j).Value2, FilterRelation, FilterCriterion2) Then SUMQ = SUMQ + NumsToSquare(i, j).Value2 ^ 2
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Function

Private Function Judge(var1 As Variant, FilterRelation As String, var2 As Variant) As Boolean
Judge = False
On Error GoTo err:
Select Case FilterRelation 'cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711633(v=vs.71).aspx
    Case "=" 'The = operator tests whether the two operands are equal.
        Judge = (var1 = var2)
    Case "<>" 'The <> operator tests whether the two operands are not equal.
        Judge = (var1 <> var2)
    Case "<" 'The < operator tests whether the first operand is less than the second operand.
        Judge = (var1 < var2)
    Case ">" 'The > operator tests whether the first operand is greater than the second operand.
        Judge = (var1 > var2)
    Case "<=" 'The <= operator tests whether the first operand is less than or equal to the second operand.
        Judge = (var1 <= var2)
    Case ">=" 'The >= operator tests whether the first operand is greater than or equal to the second operand.
        Judge = (var1 >= var2)
End Select
err:
End Function
```